# Maputnik: iso_a2 filter

Tags: mapbox-gl-js, openmaptiles, maputnik

I'd like to show place labels (cities and towns) only for the one country. Is it possible to achieve this in [Maputnik editor](https://maputnik.github.io/editor/#5.22/48.871/29.067)? I'm looking for something like Mapbox "iso_3166_1" parameter. I've tried to add iso_a2 to the layer filter settings in such way:

```
"id": "place_city",
...   
"filter": [
  "all",
   ["==", "$type", "Point"],
   ["==", "class", "city"],
   ["==", "iso_a2", "FR"]
```

but it didn't work.

Comment: Do you have attribute "iso_a2" as an attribute in your vector tiles?

Comment: No, I want to filter style.json generated in maputnik editor. It is not my style but one of the default styles ("dark matter") and it has openmaptiles as source.  Openmaptiles seems to have this iso_a2 property as indicated here https://openmaptiles.org/schema/#place  but I can't understand how to activate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general your filter is fine (there's a missing bracket `]` to close the array), but the filter doesn't give the result you want because there is only one feature with the `iso_a2` property for whole France in the source vector tiles (OpenMapTiles).

As stated in the OpenMapTiles docs, the `iso_a2` property is a

> Two-letter country code ISO 3166-1 alpha-2. Original value of the
> country_code_iso3166_1_alpha_2 tag.

https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Tag:place%3Dcountry states that this tag is useful but currently not part of map features.

In fact there is only one feature available in OSM with `country_code_iso3166_1_alpha_2=FR` and only this feature with `class=country` is available for filtering:

https://taginfo.openstreetmap.org/tags/?key=country_code_iso3166_1_alpha_2&value=FR

https://www.openstreetmap.org/node/1363947712

[image: Screenshot Maputnik]

However, if you want to show labels only for one country, you could try to use a filter with the [within expression](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/style-spec/expressions/#within) and a GeoJSON of the country geometry.

Here es an example how such a filter would look like:

https://gist.github.com/pathmapper/6b3b8955454b9bc69452493c06a72b0c#file-filter-json

Sample geometry used for this filter:

https://gist.github.com/pathmapper/6b3b8955454b9bc69452493c06a72b0c#file-polygon-geojson

Please note that this filter is currently not working with https://maputnik.github.io/editor because the GL JS version used for Maputnik `v1.7.0` has a bug with nested within expressions in filters.

If you don't want to wait for the next release (`v1.8.0`) of Maputnik to try the filter out, you could build Maputnik yourself from `master` or use this codesandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/keen-panini-7yesf

https://7yesf.sse.codesandbox.io

Here is also a filter which uses only a within exression so this one works with Maputnik `v1.7.0` which is currently available on https://maputnik.github.io/editor:

https://gist.github.com/pathmapper/6b3b8955454b9bc69452493c06a72b0c#file-filter_only_within-json

Comment: Thank you for this explanation!